# UITextView member variable is always nil in my UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uitextview

In my nib, I have a `UITextView` component.

In my `UIViewController` I have a `UITextView` member field and I have used IB to make sure that the two are connected (at least I think I did that by dragging from "Files Owner" and dropping it on the `UITextView` in IB and selecting my member variable).

Now, when I update the text via `setText:`, the `UITextView` still remains blank.

When I break into my code, the member variable (called `textView`) is `nil`.

So I am guessing I have not used IB correctly.  How can I make sure that this variable is connected to the `UITextView` graphic element?

Here is the code

```
// My interface looks like

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailsController : UIViewController 
{
    UITextView *textView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *textView; 

@end;


// and the implementation

#import "DetailsController.h"

@implementation DetailsController

@synthesize textView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) 
    {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

// used pressed the "Done" button
- (IBAction)done
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)setDetails: (NSString *)detail withQuote:(NSString *)quote
{
    NSLog(@"%@", textView);
    [textView setText:detail];
}

@end
```

Comment: did you use an IBOutlet for the textview? Post more code.

Comment: Where are you calling `setText:`? Are you sure the view has already loaded from the NIB?

Comment: Please don't double-post. See: [How do I get attention for my unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions)

Comment: Not sure your exact problem, but note that UITextFields and UITextViews are nil until the user enters something FWIW. This just burned me.

Answer (score 0):

save nib file after connecting outlet, build project and run, it should work if it's connected

Comment: I did that but it did not work.  Can you please clarify the exact steps involved in "Connecting the outlet"?

Comment: I always do it like this in IB: 1. click right mouse button on File's Owner. 2. Drag from textView outlet to UITextView control. It should look like first picture in Making Connections section: [link](http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/05_ConfiguringView.html). I guess you did it right from your description above...

Comment: Is there a way I can look at the actual XML file and see if something is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see agere you are calling setText, but I think that you try to do it in the initializer. GUI code should not be done before the viewDidLoad in the case of using XIB's or loadView if you make your GUI programatically, or the other viewWill/viewDid...  methods.

The reason is because the views are not loaded before they are actually needed, it is called lazy loading. You should Google that for more info.