# UITextView member variable is always NIL in my UIViewController

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, interface-builder, uitextview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UITextView member variable is always nil in my UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554858/uitextview-member-variable-is-always-nil-in-my-uiviewcontroller)

In my mib, I have a UITextView component.

In my UIViewController I have a UITextView member field and I have used IB to make sure that the two are connected (at least I think I did that by dragging from "Files Owner" and dropping it on the UITextView in IB and selecting my member variable).

Now, when I update the text via setText, the UITextView still remains blank.

When I break into my code, the member variable (called textView) is NIL.

So I am guessing I have not used IB correctly. How can I make sure that this variable is connected to the UITextView graphic element?

Here is the code

```
// My interface looks like

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailsController : UIViewController 
{
    UITextView *textView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *textView; 

@end;


// and the implementation

#import "DetailsController.h"

@implementation DetailsController

@synthesize textView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) 
    {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

// used pressed the "Done" button
- (IBAction)done
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)setDetails: (NSString *)detail withQuote:(NSString *)quote
{
    NSLog(@"%@", textView);
    [textView setText:detail];
}

@end`
```

Thanks
Deshawn